# How to convert epoch time to human readable date in presto with time zone as IST

Tags: datetime, timezone, presto

I have a column in a table which stores epoch time.

I want to convert it human readable date  time stamp with time zone as IST. I am using the below query, but conversion is incorrect, it is showing 05:30 previous time.

```
presto:default> select to_char(date_trunc('hour',
     from_unixtime((CAST(substr(startdatetime,1,10) AS double )))),
     'dd-mm-yyyy hh24'),startdatetime FROM rocmetricsolr limit 10;


     _col0     | startdatetime 
---------------+---------------
 NULL          | NULL          
 21-05-2018 23 | 1526905879116 
 21-05-2018 23 | 1526905879116 
 21-05-2018 23 | 1526905874892 
 NULL          | NULL          
 21-05-2018 23 | 1526905876216 
 21-05-2018 23 | 1526905876216 
 21-05-2018 23 | 1526905873640 
 21-05-2018 23 | 1526905873640 
 21-05-2018 23 | 1526905903110
```

Comment: It will be easy to do what you want when https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/7122 is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a table `rocmetricsolr` with column `startdatetime` in `varchar` type where first 10 digits present epoch timestamp:

`SELECT
    from_unixtime(CAST(substr(startdatetime,1,10) AS bigint)) AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles'`

**Note**: Please change the timezone names based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: 10 or 9 as substr is not accurate, 963865200823 and 1155657969480 gives wrong result